Is the performance of an app running in a Docker container significantly slower compared to running it outside of a container?
Is it true that the performance of an application running in a Docker container is significantly slower compared to running it outside of a container?
I tested a newly installed Laravel application using the following method:
ab -t 10 -c 10 -v 2 "http://url.ur"
Here are the RPS (requests per second) results:
Without Docker:
ab -t 10 -c 10 -v 2 "http://test.site/ab"
2723.24 [#/sec] (mean)
2744.14 [#/sec] (mean)
2739.20 [#/sec] (mean)

With Docker container:
ab -t 10 -c 10 -v 2 "http://localhost:8000/ab"
83.67 [#/sec] (mean)
88.92 [#/sec] (mean)
87.36 [#/sec] (mean)

Why is there such a significant performance difference? Is this a known issue when using Docker, or could this be due to a specific configuration problem?
Operating System and Hardware Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
RAM: 32 GB
Disk: 457 GB total, 42 GB used, 392 GB available

This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
    app:
        image: php:8.3-fpm
        container_name: laravel_app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        networks:
            - laravel_network

    webserver:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: laravel_nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - laravel_network

networks:
    laravel_network:
        driver: bridge

I tested a Laravel app using ab to compare RPS on the host vs in Docker. I had expected similar performance, but Docker's RPS was drastically lower (around 85 vs 2700).
Updated:
Here are the results on a different server:
Without Docker (ab -t 10 -c 10 -v 2 "http://185.65.202.78/ab"):
Requests per second: 43.58 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 39.66 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 39.80 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 38.40 [#/sec] (mean)

With Docker (ab -t 10 -c 10 -v 2 "http://185.65.202.78:8000/ab"):
Requests per second: 7.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 6.70 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 6.25 [#/sec] (mean)
Requests per second: 7.28 [#/sec] (mean)

The /ab route contains:
Route::middleware([])->get('/ab', function () {
    $points = [];
    $start = microtime(true);
    $points['app_boot'] = microtime(true) - $start;
    $points['response_created'] = microtime(true) - $start;
    return response()->json($points);
})->withoutMiddleware(\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class)
  ->withoutMiddleware(\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class)
  ->withoutMiddleware(\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class);

Without Docker (curl "http://185.65.202.78/ab"):
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.0011429786682128906}
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.0006058216094970703}
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.0013248920440673828}

With Docker (curl "http://185.65.202.78:8000/ab"):
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.014487028121948242}
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.01622796058654785}
{"app_boot":0,"response_created":0.014702081680297852}

You can visit the URL and check it yourself. I don't understand why there is such a big difference.

The performance of CPU operation should be as fast outside than inside. IOs operations are generally slower, but clearly not >30x times slower. A significant source of performance difference is often that the setup/version of the software inside are not the same as the one outside.

A setup where you're using Docker bind mounts to inject code from the host system into the otherwise-isolated container can be expensive, especially if you're using Docker Desktop or another similar VM-based setup.  If you're up to a point of doing performance testing, I'd consider removing the volumes: so that you're running the code built into your images, in their Dockerfiles; that specific volumes: setting can cause a performance hit in some environments.

Do you really compare a HTTP request to a remote server with a request to your local machine?

Both on local machine

I've updated the post

could it be possible that your docked Laravel is in the dev mode?

no, the code and .env the same
